# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'exist'

Tags: python, directory, python-os

I want to check if a file exists and if it does give the folder i create with `mkdir` the next higher number.
Somehow I get the `Error: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'exist'` I do not understand why that os function does not work for me. Any ideas?

```
import os
map_name="Example.png"
wk_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath('__file__'))
dir_name=os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(map_name))[0]

for n in range(0,200):
    m=n+1
    if os.path.exist(wk_dir + "/" + dir_name + "_%s_%dx%d_%d" % (a, resolution, resolution,n)):
        os.mkdir(wk_dir + "/" + dir_name + "_%s_%dx%d_%d" % (a, resolution, resolution,m))
    break
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your problem is a typo. It should be

```
os.path.exists(wk_dir + "/" + dir_name + "_%s_%dx%d_%d" % (a, resolution, resolution,n))
```

Instead of

```
os.path.exist(wk_dir + "/" + dir_name + "_%s_%dx%d_%d" % (a, resolution, resolution,n))
```

Note that `os.path.exists` returns true if there's anything with the name passed as argument, be it file or directory.

To check if a **file** exists:

```
import os
if os.path.isfile("~/myfile"):
    print("this file exists!")
else:
    print("file not found!")
```

To check if a **directory** exists:

```
import os
if os.path.isdir("~/mydir"):
    print("this directory exists!")
else:
    print("directory not found!")
```

Comment: True, wow it is always sth. like that. Sorry for bothering you with this

Comment: A truly cryptic error message had me scratching my head, and embarassed here to vote up this answer.  Thanks though!